# YQL | why I'm getting a syntax error?

Tags: url, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

I'm trying to query a simple Google search using YQL but apparently it seems not working. Here's my exact query

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com/search?q=Google+Guice&ie=utf-8%27%0A&format=json
```

And the error is

```
{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Query syntax error(s) [line 1:74 mismatched character ' ' expecting ''']"}}
```

The error is pointing to line 1:74 which is near `20where`. This is also the encoded version of the URL, and it is difficult for me to exactly understand where the error is.

Comment: You really should be able to solve this with a little bit of sleuthing. What is the *actual* unencoded query? Pay attention to the last character, after the quote (%27).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your url:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?
q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27https%3A%2F%2F
www.google.com/search?q=Google+Guice&ie=utf-8%27%0A&format=json
```

The URL query parts are separated into the following (separated by `&`):

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+
| q      | select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27https |
|        | %3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com/search?q=Google+Guice     |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+
| ie     | utf-8%27%0A                                       |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+
| format | json                                              |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, YQL is not receiving the full query string as you wanted it to. This is because the `&` character that *should* be part of the query string has not been *url-encoded* to `%26`.

The URL should look like …`Guice%26ie=utf`….

---

**Aside:** There are a few other issues that you are going to face. The first is that the Google search URL embedded into the query is malformed since it will contain a literal space character between `Google` and `Guice`, which Google does not accept. Secondly, the URL is restricted by Google's `robots.txt` so even if the URL is fixed, you won't be able to get any results from there.